# Google Apps Script fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm using a Google Apps script to get Google Calendar data. It works fine if I don't use a parameter in the URL. But I want a bit more flexibility and have a variable time span for which the calendar should be checked. I added a parameter to the entry function and manually set it to a fixed value like this: function doGet(timeSpan=600000) { do stuff }. When I use the "Execute" function in the script editor, I get the expected result. When I use the URL which is produced when I implement the script, I always get an error reponse that the end date must be later than the start date, with or without the parameter in the URL.

I added debug code to check the dates which are used to get the calendar entries using the API function cal.getEvents(start, end). When I run the script in the script editor I get
response = {"status":"debug","data":["2024-03-23T16:09:15.946Z","2024-03-30T14:49:15.946Z"]}, which is what I expect.
When I use the URL in a browser to call the script, I get
{"status":"debug","data":["2024-03-23T16:10:00.158Z",null]}. The end date is always null.

This works:

```
// Get upcoming events for the next x days from the 'Recycle' calendar
function doGet() {
  const SECOND = 1;
  const MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
  const HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
  const DAY = 24 * HOUR;
  const WEEK = 7 * DAY;
  
  var _calendarName = 'Recycle';
  //var _timeSpan = timeSpan;
  var _timeSpan = 600000;

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(getOutput(_calendarName, _timeSpan));
}

function getOutput(calendarName, timeSpan) {

  // for debugging only: show the result which will be sent to the caller
  // Logger.log('response = ' + JSON.stringify(getResponse(calendarName, timeSpan)));

  // create a JSON formatted string from the result object
  return JSON.stringify(getResponse(calendarName, timeSpan));
}

// Query the calendar using calendarName and timeSpan

function getResponse(calendarName, timeSpan) {

  // use the first (and only) calendar with the specified name

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
  
  if (!cal) {
    return {status: 'error', message: 'Error, calendar "' + calendarName + '" does not exist.'};
  }
  
  var now = new Date(),
      then = new Date();
  
  then.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + timeSpan);

  arr = [];
   arr.push(now);
   arr.push(then);
   arr.push(timeSpan);
   return {status: 'debug', data: arr};
}
```

This does not work:

```
// Get upcoming events for the next x days from the 'Recycle' calendar
function doGet(timeSpan) {
  const SECOND = 1;
  const MINUTE = 60 * SECOND;
  const HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
  const DAY = 24 * HOUR;
  const WEEK = 7 * DAY;
  
  var _calendarName = 'Recycle';
  var _timeSpan = timeSpan;
  //var _timeSpan = 600000;

  return ContentService.createTextOutput(getOutput(_calendarName, _timeSpan));
}

function getOutput(calendarName, timeSpan) {

  // for debugging only: show the result which will be sent to the caller
  // Logger.log('response = ' + JSON.stringify(getResponse(calendarName, timeSpan)));

  // create a JSON formatted string from the result object
  return JSON.stringify(getResponse(calendarName, timeSpan));
}

// Query the calendar using calendarName and timeSpan

function getResponse(calendarName, timeSpan) {

  // use the first (and only) calendar with the specified name

  var cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName(calendarName)[0];
  
  if (!cal) {
    return {status: 'error', message: 'Error, calendar "' + calendarName + '" does not exist.'};
  }
  
  var now = new Date(),
      then = new Date();
  
  then.setSeconds(now.getSeconds() + timeSpan);

  arr = [];
   arr.push(now);
   arr.push(then);
   arr.push(timeSpan);
   return {status: 'debug', data: arr};
}
```

Note: the "debug" version exits before I actually get the calendar data. The problem lies in the value of "then" which is null as a result of adding "timeSpan" to "now".

Comment: There is an event object associated with Web App endpoint trigger - [Web App Requirements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#requirements_for_web_apps)

Answer (score 0):

Getting Calendar Events for a start date and duration

Try something like this.  It uses a start date and a duration in milliseconds;  You will have to add your own calendar id's

```
function getEvents(obj) {
  const year = obj.startyear;
  const month = obj.startmonth;
  const day = obj.startday
  const dur = obj.timeSpan;
  const calids = obj.calids
  let evs = [["Calendar","Title","StartDate","Description"]]
  calids.forEach((id,i) => {
    let cal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(id);
    let start = new Date(obj.startyear,obj.startmonth -1,obj.startday);
    let end = new Date(start.valueOf() + obj.timeSpan);
    let events = cal.getEvents(start,end);
    events.forEach(ev => {
      evs.push([cal.getName(),ev.getTitle(),ev.getStartTime(),ev.getDescription()])
    })
  });
  if(evs.length > 1) {
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(evs).replace(/\],/g,'],\n'))
  }
}
function testabovefunction() {
  const DAY = 86400000;
  let myobj = {calids:[],startyear:"2024",startmonth:3,startday:1,timeSpan:10 * DAY};
  getEvents(myobj);
}
```

Comment: Almost nailed it. After endless testing I figured out that I need to access my object values using obj.parameters.key iso just object.key.
Thanks for putting me on the right track.